# reading text files in Adobe AIR

Tags: file, text, air

Recenlty i've found that not all text (.txt) files could be readed as i need in adobe air. Because of diff file encodings (unicode, utf-8, ascii).
For example:

```
 var fDataStream:FileStream;
 var textfile:File = new File ("C:\myfile.txt");
 var sContent:String;
 fDataStream = new FileStream();
 fDataStream.open(textfile,FileMode.READ);
 sContent = fDataStream.readUTFBytes(fDataStream.bytesAvailable);
 fDataStream.close ();
```

If 'myfile.txt' is not utf-8 encoded, then i get string like that "ÿþE"
I know that there is fDataStream.readMultyBytes() method, but it requries string representing file charset that can't be known beforehand (input .txt files for app could be in diff charsets). I'am out of ideas.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use    .readbytes instead of    .readUTFBytes

That should load anything you give it.

see

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#readBytes()